# Adding hours with Logstash configuration file

Tags: logstash-configuration, syslog

I'm working with logstash for 2 weeks, and I've a question about modifing the data.

The device which generate syslogs is not at the right hour, so the logs aren't at the right hour too, and I'd like to know how can I add hours to the time field for finally generate the correct timestamp.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Ruby filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) to do this.
Below sample code will add 14 days to the value in field `@timestamp`.
Replace the field name and the numeric values in second with whatever you want.

```
ruby {
code => 'event.set("@timestamp", LogStash::Timestamp.new(Time.at(event.get("@timestamp").to_f+1209600)))'
}
```